# Decrypting File In Node.js Throws Error But Able To Decrypt Using Bouncy Castle In C#

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, encryption, bouncycastle

I'm having an issue where I was given a file to decrypt along with the Key, IV and encryption method (`aes-256-ctr`). I have been struggling to decrypt this using node.js and keep running into an error saying the IV length is invalid. I was also given the method to decrypt the file using the BouncyCaste library in C#. The C# method seems to work fine with no issues with the IV. What do I need to do differently in node than what is being done here in C# to avoid this error?

Working C# Decryption (Note: IV is in the filename)

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Security;

namespace c_app
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var baseFolder = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

      // Create parameters
      var myDi = new DirectoryInfo(baseFolder);
      string keyString = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx32BitKeyxxxxxxxxxxx";
      byte[] keyBytes = ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(keyString);
      var c = CipherUtilities.GetCipher("AES/CTR/NoPadding");
      KeyParameter sk = ParameterUtilities.CreateKeyParameter("AES", keyBytes);

      // Get the IV
      var files = myDi.GetFiles("001398.20180823.000_1966151284357350418");
      var fileInfo = files[0];
      var pathSplit = fileInfo.FullName.Split('_');
      var filePath = pathSplit[0];
      var iv = long.Parse(pathSplit[1]);

      // Decrypt the file
      var base64String = File.ReadAllText(fileInfo.FullName);
      c.Init(false, new ParametersWithIV(sk, BitConverter.GetBytes(iv)));
      var inputBytesToDecrypt = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
      var decryptedBytes = c.DoFinal(inputBytesToDecrypt);
      var decryptedText = ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptedBytes);

      // Write file back to current directory
      File.WriteAllBytes(string.Format(@"{0}/decrypted.csv", myDi.FullName), decryptedBytes);
    }
  }
}
```

My attempt in Node.js

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var fs = require('fs');

var iv = Buffer.from('1966151284357350418', 'base64'); // Experimenting with encoding types like base64
var key = Buffer.from('xxxxxxxxxxxxx32BitKeyxxxxxxxxxxx');

fs.readFile('./001398.20180823.000_1966151284357350418', (err, encryptedText) => {
  if (err) throw err;

  var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-ctr', key, iv); // <--- Error thrown here
  decrypted = decipher.update(encryptedText, 'binary', 'utf8');
  decrypted += decipher.final('utf8');
  console.log(decrypted);
});
```

In case it is helpful I was also given the method for encrypting the file using BouncyCastle, which can be found here: https://pastebin.com/PWNzDum3

Comment: The reason you keep getting the error about the IV being of invalid length is because it **is** an invalid length.  Your C# code might automatically be truncating it.  Have you tried that in Node?  Also, where is the base64 logic?

Comment: So, that was my initial thought as well but take a look at this. In the method that encrypts the file (in the pastebin link) you'll see this `byte[] iv = new byte[16]; string encryptedFileName = outFileName.Replace("-Encrypted", "_" + BitConverter.ToInt64(iv, 0).ToString());` This appears to be explicitly creating a 16 bit IV code and adding it to the filename. The question is around this `ToInt64` method that turns it into something weird that I don't know how to deal with in node. That's why I was experimenting with base64.